# Position label of colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this function:

```
def scatter_diagdistance(x, y) :
    z = abs(y-x)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
    sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='none')
    x_diag = np.arange(min(x*100), max(x*100))/100
    ax.plot(x_diag, x_diag, '-', c="red")
    cbar = fig.colorbar(sc)
    cbar.set_label('Distance from diagonal')
    return(fig)
```

Which gives me this sort of image:
[image: figure generated by the code snippet]
How can I position the "Distance from diagonal" to the left of the colorbar?

(Also, is there a cleaner way to plot the diagonal over a scatter plot like this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do it is to use the text as the label for the secondary y-axis. That will keep the text before the colorbar. Also, you can draw a line for the diagonal. The code (without your data) is shown below. If you use `transform=ax.transAxes` [details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), the coordinates are interpreted as axes coordinates

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
ax2 = ax.twinx() ##Create secondary axis
ax2.set_yticks([]) ##No ticks for the secondary axis
sc = ax.scatter(0.5, 0.5, c=1, s=50, edgecolor='none') 
ax2.set_ylabel('Distance from diagonal') ##Label for secondary axis
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '-', c="red", transform=ax.transAxes) #Line from 0 to 1
cbar = fig.colorbar(sc)
```

**Plot**

[image]